# Can't find package module after installation

Tags: python

I installed the package in the following way:

```
cd /work/waterhouse_team
git clone https://github.com/freemao/schnablelab.git
added "export PYTHONPATH=/work/waterhouse_team/apps/schnablelab:PYTHONPATH" to ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

I ran

```
cd /scratch/waterhouse_team/tmp2
/scratch/waterhouse_team/tmp2> python -m schnablelab.imputation.GC vcf2map freebayes-gbs.gvcf-gt30.vcf.gz gc.map
```

but I got `python: No module named schnablelab.imputation`.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your path addition is one level too deep.

If you expect to find `schnablelab.imputation.GC` as an importable module, then the **parent directory** of that module needs to be in your path.

i.e. you need `/work/waterhouse_team/apps` in your path, not `/work/waterhouse_team/apps/schnablelab`.

And you also need the dollar sign so the existing path is maintained, as @Raydel Miranda pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be:

```
export PYTHONPATH="your/path:$PYTHONPATH"
```

You miss the `$` .